# javascript: restart SVG animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, smil

according to [MDN SVG Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement), I am trying to restart all animation of a `svg` tag by clicking on window.

```js
function restartAnimation(el){
    [
        'animate',
        'animateColor', 
        'animateMotion',
        'animateTransform',
        'set', 
    ].forEach(tag=>{
        el.querySelectorAll(tag).forEach(ele => {
            console.log(ele.getStartTime());
            ele.beginElementAt(ele.getStartTime());
        });
    });
}

window.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    restartAnimation(document.querySelector('svg'));
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="width: 50%; height: 50%;">
  <path d="M69 0L97 53L0 125" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round" id="svgPath1" style="animation: svgPath1Anim 1000ms ease-in-out 1000ms 1;">
    <animate id="animStroke1" xlink:href="#svgPath1" attributeType="XML" begin="1s" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" additive="sum" attributeName="stroke" values="silver;wheat;lightgreen"></animate>
  </path>
</svg>
```

I used to use `ele.beginElement()`, but it ignores the starting time `begin="1s"`, which the animation starts immediately without delay.

However, after change to `ele.beginElementAt(ele.getStartTime())`, it does not work properly. when I click on window, I am expecting `1` to always be logged, but it gives me accumulated non-sense which

```js
1
4.7121100425720215
11.299739837646484
```

I wonder why this happen. I will be so glad if you can fix the function for me.

---

I am currently using this

```js
function whatTime(str){
    if(str.includes('ms')){
        return parseFloat(str.slice(0, -2)) / 1000; 
    }
    return parseFloat(str.slice(0, -1)); 
}

function restartAnimation(el){
    [
        'animate',
        'animateColor', 
        'animateMotion',
        'animateTransform',
        'set', 
    ].forEach(tag=>{
        el.querySelectorAll(tag).forEach(ele => {
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        ele.beginElement();
                    }, whatTime(ele.getAttribute('begin')) * 1000);
        });
    });
}

window.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    restartAnimation(document.querySelector('svg'));
});
```

it works, but I wonder why the previous one perform oddly.

Comment: If you want to restart the animation you'd just call beginElement(), or beginElement(0)

Comment: But that ignores the ``begin="1s"`` ?